# Apache Mod Rewrite - Replace : character with another

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite all URL's that contain a ':' in it to another character. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words

Example:

```
http://example.com/some_interesting:info
http://example.com/some_interesting_info
http://example.com/some:interesting:info
http://example.com/some:interesting_info
```

would all point to this file

```
some_interesting_info
```

How can I do this?

EDIT: Did more testing

this works

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*) $1$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\_+(.*) $1$2 [L]
```

test_rewrite.html goes to testrewrite.html

this doesn't

```
RewriteRule ^(.*):(.*) $1$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\:+(.*) $1$2 [L]
```

test:rewrite.html gives a 403

In terms of eliminating the character in the middle. Tested with xammp 1.7.1

Answer (score 3):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^:]*):([^:]*:.*) /$1_$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^/([^:]*):([^:]*)$ /$1_$2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule).

```
RewriteRule ^/some[_:]interesting[_:]info$ /some_interesting_info [L]
```

Comment: That would only cover the example URLs but not all URLs that contain a colon.